# Why do I get: No valid JFX runtime

Tags: java, jnlp

I have an existing application that is compiled with java 1.6 and runs with jnlp/webstart. If I run this application from the client with JRE 1.6 everything is fine. But when I compile the code with java JDK 7 and run the client with JRE 1.7.67 I see the java 7 splash screen and nothing else seems to happen.

Below I pasted the log file....can anyone give a good reason why the application is not started? The other thing that bothers me is that the existing code was written 10 years a go and has not got any javaFX code.

```
Log started: wo, 24 dec 2014 15:59:52 +0100
Java Plug-in 10.67.2.01
Using JRE version
 1.7.0_67-b01 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
basic: No valid JFX runtime at [C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe]
basic: Running JVMParams: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args:]
    -> [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args:]
temp: new XMLParser with source:
temp: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost/test" href="db/webstart/cache.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Test app</title>
    <vendor>Implemented by Test</vendor>
    <description>Cache Cleaner</description>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7" />
    <property name="user.language" value="nl"/>
    <property name="user.country" value="NL"/>

    <jar href="lib/test.jar" main="true"/>
  </resources>

  <application-desc main-class="org.test.jnlp.CacheCleaner" >
    <argument>http://localhost/test.jnlp</argument>
  </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Since you have no JavaFX code, it's unlikely that the "No valid JFX runtime" message is related to your problem.  I would look for places in the code which are catching exceptions without logging/wrapping/re-throwing them.

Comment: <Update> 
Running the application standalone from the main works fine with Java 1.7. It seems the jnlp configuration file has a problem with 1.7 and higher....can it be that I need to change the jnlp spec version to let it work with java 7 and higher?

Answer (score 0):

From memory, when I upgraded my JDK a year or two ago I also noticed that JavaWS applications no longer launched successfully.

With a bit of Googling, I found that the default security settings had changed.

You may have the same problem, so you may have to add some URLs to an allowed list.

On a linux system I believe this was achieved by running jcontrol from the JDK.