# No valid JFX runtime

Tags: java, windows-7, java-8, jnlp

After updating from JRE `1.8_b30` to JRE `1.8_b73`, a JNLP application is no longer starting on a Windows 7 machine. The same application runs without problems on a Linux machine with JRE `1.8_b73`.

If I enable tracing, I receive the following error in `\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\log\jcp.trace`:

```
Log started: Tue, 23 Feb 2016 10:33:09 +0200
Java Plug-in 11.73.2.02
Using JRE version
 1.8.0_73-b02 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
basic: No valid JFX runtime at [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin\javaw.exe]
basic: No valid JFX runtime at [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin\javaw.exe]
basic: recv: javaws.singleinstance.stop
basic: getSingleInstanceFilename: C:\Users\user\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\tmp\si\JavaControlPanel-x86_50207
basic: getSingleInstanceFilename: C:\Users\user\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\tmp\si\JavaControlPanel-x86_50207
basic: removed SingleInstanceFile: C:\Users\user\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\tmp\si\JavaControlPanel-x86_50207
```

My application does not use JavaFX. Is there any change done by Oracle, that could affect my application?

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679260/why-do-i-get-no-valid-jfx-runtime), but it does not solve my problem.

Thank you.